# ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis - LIES?

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I have stared at this until my eyeballs bleed, where am I missing a parenthesis? It does also say

> Error starting at line: 1 in command-".

The cause and action section of the error report is blank.

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTREQUEST(
    EVENTNO VARCHAR2(8) CONSTRAINT EVENTNO_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
    DATEHELD DATE CONSTRAINT DATEHELD_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
    DATEREQ DATE CONSTRAINT DATEREQ_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
    CUSTNO VARCHAR2(8) CONSTRAINT CUSTNO_NOTNULL2 NOT NULL,
    FACNO VARCHAR2(8) CONSTRAINT CUSTNO_NOTNULL2 NOT NULL,
    DATEAUTH DATE,
    STATUS VARCHAR2(15) CHECK (STATUS IN ('Pending', 'Denied', 'Approved')) CONSTRAINT STATUS_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
    ESTCOAST VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT ESTCOAST_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
    ESTAUDIENCE VARCHAR2(30) CHECK(ESTAUDIENCE > 0) CONSTRAINT ESTAUDIENCE_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
    BUDNO VARCHAR2(8),
    CONSTRAINT PK_EVENTNO PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTONO FOREIGN KEY (CUSTNO) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTNO),
    CONSTRAINT FK_FACNO FOREIGN KEY (FACNO) REFERENCES FACILITY(FACNO)
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This just because you missed column name while declaring primary key. There is another problem: constraint name for both fourth and fifth columns are same. I have changed that too.

And there is no need to declare `CONSTRAINT EVENTNO_NOTNULL NOT NULL` since you are declaring it as primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTREQUEST(
EVENTNO VARCHAR2(8) CONSTRAINT EVENTNO_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
DATEHELD DATE CONSTRAINT DATEHELD_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
DATEREQ DATE CONSTRAINT DATEREQ_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
CUSTNO VARCHAR2(8) CONSTRAINT CUSTNO_NOTNULL2 NOT NULL,
FACNO VARCHAR2(8) CONSTRAINT FACNO_NOTNULL2 NOT NULL,
DATEAUTH DATE,
STATUS VARCHAR2(15) CHECK (STATUS IN ('Pending', 'Denied', 'Approved')) CONSTRAINT STATUS_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
ESTCOAST VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT ESTCOAST_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
ESTAUDIENCE VARCHAR2(30) CHECK(ESTAUDIENCE > 0) CONSTRAINT ESTAUDIENCE_NOTNULL NOT NULL,
BUDNO VARCHAR2(8),
CONSTRAINT PK_EVENTNO PRIMARY KEY (EVENTNO),
CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTONO FOREIGN KEY (CUSTNO) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTNO),
CONSTRAINT FK_FACNO FOREIGN KEY (FACNO) REFERENCES FACILITY(FACNO));
```